# How to remove the noise from cycle-based signal to get better result of filtering via Fourier transform

Tags: python, scipy, signals, signal-processing, fft

I was working on filtering signals via Fourier Transforms using Python.

The raw signal was produced from some instruments which should contains the cycle-based singals with fluctuation. An example is shown as follows:

[image]

My aim is to extract every plateau of each cycle as one individual sample. With FFT-based method, I tried to firstly get a more smooth curve, and then use differential method to get the abrupt change point (largest/lowest differential value). Based on the starting point and ending point (showing in figure below), I could identify every individual sample which containing a few data point
[image]

However, this method met problem because the raw signals also included some non-sense signal which were not useful but leading to worse result of FFT filtering.

Here is the code and the results which I used part of the data and the whole time series. We could see in subplot 2 that the filtered signals could not reflect the actual flucation of the cycle of raw signal due to the influence of noises in the end.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import fftpack
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, general_gaussian, fftconvolve

test = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/envhyf/Notebook/master/example_raw_signal.csv")

def fft_filter(sig):
    time_step = 1
    period = len(sig)
    time_vec  = np.arange(0, period,time_step)

    # reference: https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/scipy/auto_examples/plot_fftpack.html
    sig_fft = fftpack.fft(sig)
    
    power = np.abs(sig_fft)**2
    sample_freq = fftpack.fftfreq(sig.size, d=time_step)

    
    pos_mask = np.where(sample_freq > 0)
    freqs = sample_freq[pos_mask]
    peak_freq = freqs[power[pos_mask].argmax()]
    
    high_freq_fft = sig_fft.copy()
    high_freq_fft[np.abs(sample_freq) > peak_freq] = 0
    filtered_sig = fftpack.ifft(high_freq_fft)

    return filtered_sig

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

##########only extract part of the signal#######################
ax = plt.subplot(211)
sig          = cutting_sig(test).F2.values[0:600]
sig_filtered = fft_filter(sig)
period    = len(sig)
time_step = 1
time_vec  = np.arange(0, period,time_step)


plt.plot(time_vec, sig, label='Original signal')
plt.plot(time_vec,sig_filtered , linewidth=2, label='Filtered signal')


deriv = np.diff(sig_filtered)
pos_peaks, pos_details = find_peaks(deriv)
neg_peaks, neg_details = find_peaks(-deriv)
plt.scatter(time_vec[pos_peaks], sig_filtered[pos_peaks],color = 'r')
plt.scatter(time_vec[neg_peaks], sig_filtered[neg_peaks],color = 'k')

plt.title('Part of the data')
plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
plt.legend(loc='best')

#######################################################################
ax = plt.subplot(212)
sig          = cutting_sig(test).F2.values#[0:600]
sig_filtered = fft_filter(sig)
period    = len(sig)
time_step = 1
time_vec  = np.arange(0, period,time_step)


plt.plot(time_vec, sig, label='Original signal')
plt.plot(time_vec,sig_filtered , linewidth=2, label='Filtered signal')


deriv = np.diff(sig_filtered)
pos_peaks, pos_details = find_peaks(deriv)
neg_peaks, neg_details = find_peaks(-deriv)
plt.scatter(time_vec[pos_peaks], sig_filtered[pos_peaks],color = 'r')
plt.scatter(time_vec[neg_peaks], sig_filtered[neg_peaks],color = 'k')
plt.title('Whole series')

plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

So, my question is how to remove those noises in advance and then conduct FFT filtering to achieve my target? I could not figure out the method to get rid of those bad data points out.